# How do I run a PowerShell script "in" IIS?

Tags: iis, powershell, web-config, iis-6

I'm reading up on a particular command (SET-WEBCONFIGURATIONPROPERTY) and I'm getting the `"is not recognized as a cmdlet"` error. Suggests to me that I'm missing a snap-in of some sort, even though I'm using the `SharePoint PowerShell`, which I was under the impression came with most.

On reading up a bit, a lot of the examples seem to display `"IIS:> SET-WEB....."`.

1. How have they managed to work within `IIS in the PowerShell console`?
2. Is there a special PowerShell console or am I missing a snap-in?

Comment: Check out my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260338/how-to-manage-iis-site-using-power-shell

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy, you've answered my question. I'm not sure whether this question should be deleted (given the fact it already exists) or whether you should post it as an answer so I can mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
cd IIS:
```